# How does changing GAN training method afftects the GAN?

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, gradient-descent, gan, multiobjective

I am training a GAN in which I am optimizing or reducing the loss of the generator and the discriminator simultaneously. However, the images generated are very noisy. What could be the hidden reason? Why the simultaneous optimization of the loss functions does not ensure good images in GAN? Generally GANs are trained by optimizing the loss functions alternatively.

Comment: no, the optimization usually alternates, gradient ascent-descent in GAN has been proven to be unstable, since the 2 nets are going to run in circle

Comment: I am optimizing the two loss functions in a common descent direction. There is no ascent or descent rather only descent in a common descnet direction.

Comment: Yes, because $\max F = \min -F$, but it's the same, the method is called gradient ascent-descent, look it up

Comment: Yes ultimately its the same, so if I minimize both the functions in a common descent direction(multi-objective gradient descent) then what is the harm in it? Is it changing the basic idea of GAN in anyway?

Comment: I mean instead of optmizing the loss functions seperately, I did optimize them together at a time.

Comment: I found a slightly more detailed motivation here https://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-gradient-descent-work-to-optimize-generative-adversarial-networks. Basically it’s what Alberto says.